# Boost::function bound member function becomes invalid

Tags: c++, boost-thread, boost-bind, boost-function

I have a simple thread pool implementation using `boost::function`, and `boost::bind` to reduce the member function signature to `void func(void)`. This then uses a queue of `boost::function` and `int` pairs, pops the top of the queue, and executes the function (all wrapped in a mutex block).

```
threadPool->addJob(boost::bind(&Foo::bar, this, arg1, arg2));

...

typedef boost::function<void(void)> func;
std::queue<std::pair<func, int> > funcQ;

void ThreadPool::addJob(func f){
    funcQ.push(std::make_pair(f, j));
}

if (!funcQ.empty()){
    func localFunc = (funcQ.front()).first;
    ...
    funcQ.pop();
    ...
    localFunc();
}
```

However, after a few iterations, this was causing a segfault when I invoked the `()` operator on the function, so I tossed in an assert statement to make sure that the function was callable:

```
...
assert(funcQ.front().first);
func localFunc = (funcQ.front()).first;
...
```

Lo and behold, after a few iterations the assert trips, indicating that my `boost::function` was not callable.

I first thought that perhaps the function data (from the `Foo` class) had been destroyed before the function was called, however as I understand it, `boost::function` creates a copy of the data to form the closure anyhow. Unfortunately I don't know enough about what causes `boost::function`s to be invalid to progress any further on the problem. Am I binding the member function incorrectly, or does the problem lie somewhere between there and trying to call it?

Edit: I should have mentioned: `Foo` is allocated on the heap, and isn't `delete`d until the threads are joined.

Comment: `boost::function` will create a copy of the `this` pointer you pass it, i.e. it keeps a pointer with the same address. It does not own a copy of `*this`.

Answer (score 1):

std::queue is not thread safe. When you say you are using mutex for popping from the queue, I understand you will be doing the same for pushing in the queue.

Also, you need to take care of the lifetime of Foo. Consider passing a shared_ptr to asynchronous functions. (shared_from_this() instead of this)

Note: You can use boost::asio to achieve task scheduling.
Here is a very good article on that
http://www.gamedev.net/blog/950/entry-2249317-a-guide-to-getting-started-with-boostasio/

Comment: I am indeed wrapping every time the queue is accessed in a mutex. Foo is allocated on the heap, and the destructor isn't called until the threads are joined. Also, I made this to try and understand how to use boost::function and boost::bind, but I will definitely look into boost::asio, thanks!